# How to print output filename to console using ImageMagick "convert" tool?

Tags: imagemagick, output, filenames, imagemagick-convert

When i convert images using ImageMagick "convert" tool i want to get filenames of the created files.

Using "-monitor" command-line argument i can get only input filenames.

Comment: How can you fail to know what file you are creating? It was at the end of the command you gave, surely? What command are you running such that you don't know what you are creating?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, ImageMagick can generate multiple output files for a single input. Without runing the command can you please tell me what file would be created "convert rose: rose: rose: image_%04d.png"?

Comment: I have posted a couple of workable ideas...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

The simplest, and most direct, way of doing this is to use the `-verbose` option as follows:

```
convert rose: rose: rose: -verbose image_%04d.png
rose:=>image_0000.png[0] PPM 70x46 70x46+0+0 8-bit sRGB 6.97KB 0.000u 0:00.000
rose:=>image_0001.png[1] PPM 70x46 70x46+0+0 8-bit sRGB 6.97KB 0.000u 0:00.000
rose:=>image_0002.png[2] PPM 70x46 70x46+0+0 8-bit sRGB 6.97KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

It took several iterations and far too much dinking around for me to get there, but I'll leave my earlier ideas below in case anyone wants to try out some *"off the wall"* and, let's say, *"contrived"*, ways of doing similar things...

**Option 1**

You can use the `%p` escape sequence and `-format` and `+identify` like this:

```
convert rose: rose: rose: -format "image_%p.png\n" -identify image_%04d.png
image_0.png
image_1.png
image_2.png
```

Yes, I know it's not quite perfect, but it may be good enough to get you started.

**Option 2**

This might be another option:

```
convert rose: rose: rose: -verbose +identify 'rose-%04d.png' | grep png
rose:=>rose-0000.png[0] PPM 70x46 70x46+0+0 8-bit sRGB 7.06KB 0.000u 0:00.000
rose:=>rose-0001.png[1] PPM 70x46 70x46+0+0 8-bit sRGB 7.06KB 0.000u 0:00.000
rose:=>rose-0002.png[2] PPM 70x46 70x46+0+0 8-bit sRGB 7.06KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

**Option 3**

```
convert -debug "Trace" rose: rose: rose: image_%04d.png 2>&1 | grep "\.png" | sort -u
image_%04d.png
image_0000.png
image_0001.png
image_0002.png
```

**Option 4**

Yet another option might be to create a file to mark the current time, and then run your command and find any newer files than the one you created before you started:

```
touch b4; sleep 1; convert rose: rose: rose: image_%04d.png

find . -newer b4

./image_0000.png
./image_0001.png
./image_0002.png
```

**Option 5**

Yet another option using the `%o` (output filename) escape you suggest - along with `-verbose`

```
convert rose: rose: rose: -format "%o" -verbose -identify image_%04d.png
rose:=>image_0000.png[0] PPM 70x46 70x46+0+0 8-bit sRGB 6.97KB 0.000u 0:00.000
rose:=>image_0001.png[1] PPM 70x46 70x46+0+0 8-bit sRGB 6.97KB 0.000u 0:00.000
rose:=>image_0002.png[2] PPM 70x46 70x46+0+0 8-bit sRGB 6.97KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: Using percent escapes (%o - output filename) output nothing. But with -verbose(option 2) i've got what i want. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent! I'll add it in as another option so they are all listed for all to see!

Comment: The only thing that i was looking for is "-verbose". It gives all the needed info about created files. All other options like "-identify" and "-format" is not needed. Thank you.

Comment: please make "-verbose" argument as the main unswer (you can leave all other options there) so i can accept your unswer.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get there, but glad we got you there in the end. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [Mark Setchel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33143628/53013), I did this to get the file names:

```
FILES=( $(
  convert <arguments> \
    -format "%o\n" -verbose -identify \
    <output> \
    2>&1 > /dev/null | sed -nEe 's/.*=>(.*)\[.*/\1/p'
) )
```

For example:

```
$ FILES=( $(
  convert rose: \
    \( -clone 0 -modulate 100,100,33.3 \) \
    \( -clone 0 -modulate 100,100,66.6 \) \
    -format "%o\n" -verbose -identify \
    rose.png \
    2>&1 > /dev/null | sed -nEe 's/.*=>(.*)\[.*/\1/p'
) )
$ echo ${FILES[0]}
rose-0.png
$ echo ${FILES[1]}
rose-1.png
$ echo ${FILES[2]}
rose-2.png
$ echo ${#FILES[@]}
3
```

Answer (score -2):

This is more of a workaround... If you use a variable to specify the output ahead of time, you can get the output from the variable. Here's an example using a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
export fn="fuzzy-magick"
export inp="$fn.png"
export outp="$fn.gif"
convert $inp $outp
echo "Output was "$outp
```

Comment: This will not help i the situations where imagemagick generates multiple files. But parsing the command-line arguments to get the output file provided by user may be partial solution.